# Как ограничить видимость файлов в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, frontend

Если открыть вкладку "Source" в хроме (F12) то будут видны файлы проекта

(HTML, CSS и т.д)

Можно ли ограничить видимость данных файлов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отдай скрипты прямо в html через php через вставку кода внутрь тега)

Comment: Нет. Всё что вы отдали в браузер можно прочитать.

Comment: Соглашусь с коллегой. Обфусцируйте код, если дело в попытке крыть его внутренности.

Comment: Вы никак не сможете скрыть код от клиента, только лишь обфусцировать `.js`

Или же запретить правый клик (**Но не делайте этого!**)

Comment: Обфускация это так же работающий код? Он просто не читабелен?

Answer (score 0):

С некоторым успехом можно спрятать только JavaScript, при помощи обфускации. Код для скачивания все еще будет доступен, но он будет нечитабелен.

Например может помочь различная минификация:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.foo = function(argument1, argument2){
        var addedArgs = parseInt(argument1)+parseInt(argument2);
        return addedArgs;
    }
    var anonymousInnerFunction = function(){
        // do stuff here!
    }
}
```

Такой код можно превратить в

```
var _0xd799=["\x66\x6F\x6F"];function MyClass(){this[_0xd799[0]]=function (_0xefcax2,_0xefcax3){var _0xefcax4=parseInt(_0xefcax2)+parseInt(_0xefcax3);return _0xefcax4;} ;var _0xefcax5=function (){} ;} ;
```